# Using precompiled JSON descriptor with iron-component-page

Tags: json, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, google-web-component

My main goal is to make documentation for my Rest API, not to a web-component.

I'm trying to use Polymer **iron-component-page** and write the documents in seperate files.
The [iron-component-page](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-component-page#property-docSrc) has a property called `docSrc` - 
*The URL to a precompiled JSON descriptor....*

I can't find anywhere what is a **precompiled JSON descriptor**, or what properties it has, with that information I will write my own.

Thank you, Noam